# QtCreator and CMake: debug a release build

Tags: c++, debugging, cmake, gdb, qt-creator

I want to debug a CMake project build for release with QtCreator. I just need to be able to generally step through the code and stop at breakpoints (I know that if there are optimizations I won't be able to browse variables and stepping maybe erratic).

I have tried to rebuild the project with -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release and add any of -Og, -O1, -O2, to the add_compile_options() in the CMakeLists.txt (building in linux with gcc). However, when I press debug in QtCreator I get the message "This does not seem to be a "Debug" build. Setting breakpoints by file name and line number may fail." and indeed the code doesn't stop at any breakpoint.

I think this should work, but I wonder if QtCreator knows that I run CMake with -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release and it's not going to let me debug even if I added -Og to the code. Is this the case? how can I workaround this?

Comment: Does setting build type to `RelWithDebInfo` help?

Comment: That worked! If you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Is it possible to inspect variables with the RelWithDebInfo builds?

Comment: Yes you can inspect variables and it runs as fast as with Release setting

Comment: @martinako Thank you for the response. I found that not all variables are available for inspection like in a normal debug session. Is there something else that you must do to have the same experience as a normal debug session?
I am using QtCreator4.15.1 and Qt 6.2.0

Comment: @TheunsHeydenrych you could try to add -g and -Og  or -O0 in the add_compile_options() and see if that shows all variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get both optimized and debuggable build, you can set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to [`RelWithDebInfo`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html).

Comment: Can variables values be inspected in debug mode  with a RelWithDebInfo  build.